# How to create a Lambda Function in Python 2.7 to Create, Reboot, Delete, Modify a ElastiCache Redis?

Tags: python, python-2.7, lambda, aws-lambda, amazon-elasticache

Currently I'm working on Lambda function to create, reboot, delete, modify a ElastiCache Redis using Python 2.7 script.
For this I need IAM rules and Policies also.
 I'm done with EC2, RDS with Stop & Start actions. I have not seen any solutions for ElastiCache Redis, So Can you people anyone provide me scripts or solutions at least to Delete, Create a ElastiCache Redis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [AWS ElastiCache Python SDK](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html) to Create, Reboot, Delete & Modify using boto3.

- Create: [create_cache_cluster()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html#ElastiCache.Client.create_cache_cluster)
- Reboot: [reboot_cache_cluster()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html#ElastiCache.Client.reboot_cache_cluster)
- Delete: [delete_cache_cluster()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html#ElastiCache.Client.delete_cache_cluster)
- Modify: [modify_cache_cluster()](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html#ElastiCache.Client.modify_cache_cluster)

example:

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('elasticache')
response = client.create_cache_cluster(
    CacheClusterId='string',
    ReplicationGroupId='string',
    AZMode='single-az'|'cross-az',
    PreferredAvailabilityZone='string',
    PreferredAvailabilityZones=[
        'string',
    ],
    NumCacheNodes=123,
    CacheNodeType='string',
    Engine='string',
    EngineVersion='string',
    CacheParameterGroupName='string',
    CacheSubnetGroupName='string',
    CacheSecurityGroupNames=[
        'string',
    ],
    SecurityGroupIds=[
        'string',
    ],
    Tags=[
        {
            'Key': 'string',
            'Value': 'string'
        },
    ],
    SnapshotArns=[
        'string',
    ],
    SnapshotName='string',
    PreferredMaintenanceWindow='string',
    Port=123,
    NotificationTopicArn='string',
    AutoMinorVersionUpgrade=True|False,
    SnapshotRetentionLimit=123,
    SnapshotWindow='string',
    AuthToken='string'
)
```

For more details on parameters refer [this](http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/elasticache.html#ElastiCache.Client.create_cache_cluster) link.

Comment: Ashan, I tried this but I did not get solution. I want to know the way to present the code in Lambda Function to make it work.

Comment: Did you assign a IAM role with required permission  for the Lambda to access ElastiCache?

Comment: Yes, I given Full access. Can you provide me exact code in python.

Comment: I just updated the answer with example code from SDK documentation.

Comment: I'll try and let you know.

Comment: Ashan, I ran ur script as below and got success, but still I am facing below error message after executing script.

Comment: import boto3
client = boto3.client('elasticache')
response = client.create_cache_cluster(
    CacheClusterId='redis',
    PreferredAvailabilityZone='us-east-1d',
    PreferredAvailabilityZones=[
        'us-east-1d',
    ],
    NumCacheNodes=1,
    CacheNodeType='cache.t1.micro',
    Engine='redis',
    EngineVersion='3.2.4',
    CacheParameterGroupName='default.redis3.2',
    CacheSubnetGroupName='default',
    SecurityGroupIds=[
        'default',
    ],
    Port=6379,
    AutoMinorVersionUpgrade=False
)

Comment: {
  "errorMessage": "Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function'"
}

START RequestId: 9783b534-873f-11e7-8552-61245a5a29a0 Version: $LATEST
Handler 'lambda_handler' missing on module 'lambda_function': 'module' object has no attribute 'lambda_handler'

END RequestId: 9783b534-873f-11e7-8552-61245a5a29a0
REPORT RequestId: 9783b534-873f-11e7-8552-61245a5a29a0 Duration: 0.41 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms  Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 30 MB

Comment: Thank You Ashan, finally I succeed

Comment: import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 client = boto3.client('elasticache')
 response = client.reboot_cache_cluster(
    CacheClusterId='rajuredis'
 CacheNodeIdsToReboot=[
  'rajuredis'
 ]
)

Comment: For my above reboot case, I am getting errors as Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 7)

Comment: import boto3

def lambda_handler(event, context):
 client = boto3.client('elasticache')
 response = client.reboot_cache_cluster(
    CacheClusterId='rajuredis'
 CacheNodeIdsToReboot=[
  '0001'
 ]
)

Comment: succeeded after modifying CacheNodeIdsToReboot

Comment: `import boto3
 instances = ['i-xyz']
 def lambda_handler(event, context):
    ec2 = boto3.client('ec2', region_name='us-east-1')
    ec2.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
    client = boto3.client('rds')
    response = client.stop_db_instance(DBInstanceIdentifier='db')
    client = boto3.client('elasticache')
    response = client.delete_cache_cluster(
    CacheClusterId='redis'
)`

Comment: Ashan,

I'm trying to do all these actions in one Python 2.7 script with lambda, but I'm seeing errors related to syntax and indent, can you help me?

Comment: @Raju I'm not quite familiar with Python syntax. So I'm not sure I would be able to help you. Anything related to AWS I should be able to help.